# Divs behaving erratically. On Collapse and Collapse in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you would notice my when you click on the Bar1 the bar will go down and come up a little. It like flickers when the div gets expanded. Please check the code.

I have used a toggle which is initially collapse in for now. But once you click on the Bar1 the div will close. And when you click on it again it will drop down and behave a bit strange. Readjusting itself like flickering. I am not able to find out what the problem is and how to fix it. Please provide some help.

```
<div class="container" id="container">
<div class="row" id="header"> <!-- Header -->
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="logo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main">
    ABC<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" id="icon" ></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="main"> <!-- Main -->
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row mystyle"> <!-- Buttons -->
      <div class="col-xs-6" id="buttons">
        <button id="video-button" class="btn btn-sample btn-block">Detail1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" id="buttons">
        <button id="channel-button" class="btn btn-sample btn-block">Detail2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Detail Starts from here! -->
  <div class="row video-main-style" id="video-detail">
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="video-name">
        <h1>ABC</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--  goes here -->
    <div class="row main-style">
      <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#views-compared-data">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="views-compared">Bar1<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" id="icon-accord"></span></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="views-compared-data">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            Some random data<br />
            More randomn data<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 400px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#header {
    background-color: #6C6D70;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2DB5AB;
    height: 50px;
}
#logo {
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#arrow-down {
    color:white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:0px;
    font-weight: strong;
}
.mystyle{
    padding:20px;
}

#buttons {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;

}
#video-name h1{

    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2DB5AB;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.main-style{
    padding: 0px 40px 10px 40px;
}

.video-main-style{
    padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
}

#views-compared{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background: #E6E7E8;
    color:#6C6D70;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#views-compared-data{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

PS Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11hgabku/3/) of the above code.

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle? And what version of jquery are you using

Comment: jquery version 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bootstrap as well, based on your class names, you should add the class `collase` or `collapse in` (depending on whether you want it closed or opened by default) to your data row having the data, like so

```
<div class="row collapse" id="views-compared-data">
...
</div>
```

The behaviour you see is adding of the `collapse` class on the first toggle.

see [opened by default](https://jsfiddle.net/11hgabku/5/) and [closed by default](https://jsfiddle.net/11hgabku/4/)